# Как использовать прототип memset

Tags: c

void *memset( const void *str, int ch, size_t n ); Вот, как выглядит прототип memset(). Не могу понять как написать с ним программу даже самую примитивную с использованием прототипа memset(). Только с использованием массива типа int.

```
void *memset( const void *x, int y, size_t z );

int main()
{
    int a[5]={5,6,7,8};
    int size =5;
    int d= '3';

    memset(a,d,size)
}

void *memset( const void *x, int y, size_t z )
{

}
```

Comment: Вы [man memset](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) уже прочли? Если да, то что именно в возможной реализации (вы же хотите сами написать код `memset()`, я угадал?) вам не понятно?

Comment: да, я читала и мне всё равно не понятно, я понимаю, как написать memset  без функции, но не понимаю, как написать через функцию

Comment: Т.е. вы понимаете, что `memset` заносит *младший байт `y`* в **первые `z` байт** по адресу `x`  (я беру имена из вашего прототипа) и не понимаете как  это сделать внутри функции?

Comment: `const` лишний.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен, что понял ваш вопрос правильно... вам нужна реализация стандартной функции `memset`?

```
void* memset(void *dest, int c, size_t count) {
  char* p = (char*)dest;
  while (count-- > 0) *p++ = c;
  return dest;
}
```

У вас, кстати, неправильный заголовок - первый параметр не может быть `const`, потому что функция должна его модифицировать.

---

Оптимизированная версия, копирует 8-байтовыми словами:

```
#define MIN_SIZE_TO_OPTIMIZE        64

void* memset(void *dest, int c, size_t count) {
  char* p = (char*)dest;

  if (count >= MIN_SIZE_TO_OPTIMIZE) {
    // Выравнять p на границу 8-ми байт
    size_t len = (uintptr_t)p & ~7;
    count -= len;
    while (len-- > 0) *p++ = c;

    // Копировать 8-байтовыми словами
    uint64_t c64 = (c & 0xFF) * 0x0101010101010101ull;
    len = count >> 3;
    while (len-- > 0) {
      *((uint64_t*)p) = c64;
      p += sizeof(uint64_t);
    }

    count &= 7;  // Остаток от 0 до 7 байт
  }

  while (count-- > 0) *p++ = c;
  return dest;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте уж для развития читателей вариант с alignment

Comment: @avp, не понял о чем вы. Если о `wmemset`, так ее реализация ничем не отличается, только вместо `char` там `wchar_t`. Специального выравнивания там тоже не нужно поскольку буфер у ней `wchar_t*`.

Comment: Об эффективной реализации, которая пытается прописывать память кусками размером size_t

Comment: @avp, не думаю, что такая нудятина будет кому-то особо интересна, но дополнил.

Comment: Я думал, вы найдете что-то вроде [этого](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/memset.c)

Comment: @avp, ну для этого уже всерьез надо голову ломать, а я тут все же не на работе. Это вариант конечно лучше, я не додумался начало буфера выравнивать. Только надо все-таки не по 4 байта, или делать два варианта с условной трансляцией.

Comment: @avp, убрал свой вариант чтобы не позориться, зря только 20 минут убил. :(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86774/discussion-between-avp-and-freim).